# How do I fork a branch of a repo into a new repository?

Tags: git, github, repository, branch, git-fork

Team A at my company has developed an application framework and it is available at https://git.mycompany.com/teama/theirproject.  Under `theirproject` are `dir1`, `dir2`, `file1`, `file2`, etc.

My team (Team B) wants to implement applications using that framework.  Team A told me that we have to fork their project, and we have to use a particular branch (let's call it `branch1`).

My team wants to create a new repo for our applications at https://git.mycompany.com/teamb/ourproject.  Our repo will look just like Team A's repo, so under `ourproject` we'll have `dir1`, `dir2`, `file1`, `file2` just like Team A does.

How do I fork the `branch1` branch of `theirproject` into https://git.mycompany.com/teamb/ourproject?  Can it be done completely from the command line, or do some things need to be done from our GitHub Enterprise website?

Note that I haven't even created the `ourproject` repo yet (although I can easily do so).  I am new to git and wasn't sure if there's a way to have the `ourproject` repo created as a part of forking `branch1` of `theirproject`.

Comment: July 2022: This is possible, but only for the [*default* branch of a repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73142169/6309).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup `theirproject` repo as an upstream in `ourproject` repo and setup tracking branch for `branch1` of `theirproject` repo.

1) Setup `ourproject` repo, ideally empty one.

2) Clone `ourproject`

3) Add `theirproject` as an upstream. `git remote add their_upstream https://git.mycompany.com/teama/theirproject.git`

4) Setup integration branch. `git checkout -b incoming_branch`

5) Pull code from `their_upstream:branch1`. `git pull their_upstream branch1`

6) Push to your repo. `git push origin`. First time you need to do `git push origin --set-upstream incoming_branch`

7) Merge `incoming_branch` to your `master` or `develop` by a PR.

8) Repeat 5~7 as often as you want.

Bonus: You can push code that you want to contribute back to `theirproject` by pushing code to `their_upstream:new_fw_feature` and creating a PR in `theirproject` repo.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  You mentioned a `develop` branch in step 7. Is that a special branch in git?  Team A's `branch1` is actually named `develop`.  Also, I found out there is a Team C that did what I'm trying to do, although I don't know what steps they performed, and I'm not sure if they forked the `master` or `develop` branch.  At the top of https://git.mycompany.com/teamc/theirproject, it says `teamc/theirproject` and right below that it says `forked from teama/theirproject`.  If I follow your steps, do you know if our page will also say `forked from teama/theirproject`?

Comment: ```develop``` is a kind of defacto branch name for all code actively under development. When you create a new repo, it comes with ```master``` branch. Some teams create ```develop``` and ```release``` to hold respective codes. But you have freedom to choose appropriate names based on team preference. When you fork, you get a full copy of the original repo along with all branches. And github knows the relation. That how it shows 'forked from...' in website. With my steps, you won't see that, but still they are connected with upstream link in the background.

Comment: Would you happen to know the procedure for forking into `teamb/ourproject` and having the website show `forked from teama/theirproject`?

Comment: When you open teama/theirproject page, you will see a fork button. When you click that, it will ask you to choose target location for forking. Assuming you are logged in into your account and you have rights to fork into teamb account, you would see both options. Just select teamb instead of your account. Github, uses theirproject as the repo name. So you will get teamb/theirproject as your repo name. Bitbucket let's you choose a different name while forking, but I think with github, you may have to rename repo if team is particular about repo name.