# Git_GitHub Fork only master branch of a repo

Tags: git, github, fork

I'm working on [this](https://github.com/openhwgroup/cv32e40p) project. As it is fairly big, the upstream repo has quite a few branches, but what I really care about is the master branch. I need to fork the repo and create a new branch, starting from actual status of master. I don't care about all otheres "work in progress" branches, I will have my own branches.

Is there a way to fork the repo, but only the master branch, to keep things clean from my perspective.
Would this cause problems if later I try to issue a merge request?

Thanks,
Andrea

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding GitHub, this is now (July 2022, 2 years later) possible.

> ### [You can now fork a repo and copy only the default branch](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-07-27-you-can-now-fork-a-repo-and-copy-only-the-default-branch/)
>
> Previously, when creating a fork all branches from the parent repository were copied to the new fork repository.
>
> There are several scenarios where this is unneeded, such as contributing to open-source projects.
> When all branches are copied, it could result in slow repo cloning and unnecessary disk usage.
>
> **With this new feature, only the default branch is copied**; no other branches or tags.
> This may result in faster clones because only reachable objects will be pulled down.
>
> [image: New fork page with ability to copy only the default branch]
>
> If you want to copy additional branches from the parent repository, you can do so from the Branches page.
>
> - [Read more about copying additional branches](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository).
> - [Read more about branches](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-branches).
> - [Read more about working with forks](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/about-forks).

Comment: It's a handy feature, I love it!
But it seems only on the GitHub website not included in the (current) latest release of Enterprise Server 3.6.2 yet.

Comment: @Trout.Z Indeed. I hope it will come there too.

Comment: @Trout.Z It is there for [GHE 3.7 though](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.7/admin/release-notes): "When forking a repository, users can choose to only include the repository's default branch in the fork.". See [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.7/get-started/quickstart/fork-a-repo).