# When should I choose 'copy the main branch only' option when forking in git?

Tags: git, git-fork

I'm learning git and I wanted to fork a repository. The video from which I'm learning it was posted few years ago and the option doesn't emerge.

When should I choose this option? And when shouldn't?

I did some research but didn't find any inofrmation as to when I should do this and when shouldn't. I only saw that this option is now available

[image]

Comment: You might only want main, and not any other branches?

Comment: You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61246036/git-github-fork-only-master-branch-of-a-repo) insightful?

Comment: @evolutionxbox in what case would I want only the main branch? (I'm a total newbie in Git yet, the question may seem silly, but I really can't grasp the difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some Git project have quite a large amount of branches.

When forking a repository, that checkbox allows you to only fork the `main` branch.

Depending if you need those branches besides `master`, you can choose not to clone them.

Lets say you want to continue work on branch `feature-FOO`, then you'll need it, but are you just forking to start a new branch from `master`, then there is no need to fork all the branches.

---

So to add an example, forking [ffmpeg](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) with that option enabled will (currently) prevent another **35** branches from being forked, which when not needed will keep your branch list a lot smaller.